# How can I test a destroy method of a bean is effectively called in a springboot integration test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

My configuration class looks like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public CassandraClient cassandraClient() { ... }
}
```

My `CassandraClient` class has a `close()` method, which is being invoked when the application context shuts down (I see it through step debugging). However, I can't find a way to test that the `close()` method is effectively called.

Here is what I would like to test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ApplicationIntegrationTests implements ApplicationContextAware {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    CassandraClient cassandraClient;

    @Test
    public void cassandraClientCloseIsCalled() {
       ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext).close();
       // How can I check that cassandraClient.close() has been called once ?
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

I tried adding an aspect to my configuration class to do the counting, but I can't get a pointcut to match the `close` method. It seems like my aspect is being destroyed before the `cassandraClient` bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this question has been here for a while, I looked into this and found a solution that works for me. You can look at it here: [Testing Nuts Example](https://github.com/jesperancinha/jeorg-spring-5-test-drives/blob/master/jeorg-spring-5/jeorg-spring-flash/jeorg-spring-flash-set-2/jeorg-spring-flash-2-19/src/test/java/org/jesperancinha/std/flash219/beans/configuration/NutsMethodsConfigurationTest.java). Essentially, almond is a nut that I create using the nut object. Both the init and the destroy methods are private, so I create an extension in another configuration in order to create a mock and be able to verify it with Mockito. This way I can shadow the private methods and generate public methods for this test. But what I think it's interesting in this case for you is that using the @PreDestroy annotation in my @Configuration for the @Test, I can then test the destroy method, just because at that point, all destroy methods have been called. Here is a copy of my code here just to clarify this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {NutsConfiguration.class, NutsMethodsConfigurationTest.NutsTestConfiguration.class})
class NutsMethodsConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    public Nut almond;

    @MockBean
    public static NutExtended nutExtended;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    void almond() {
        ConsolerizerComposer.outSpace()
                .orange(almond)
                .orange(nutExtended)
                .reset();

        verify(nutExtended, times(1)).initiate();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class NutsTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Qualifier("nut")
        public NutExtended nut() {
            return new NutExtended();
        }

        @PreDestroy
        public void check() {
            verify(nutExtended, times(1)).goToCake();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class NutExtended extends Nut {

        public void goToCake() {
            BROWN.printGenericLn("Going to cake...");
        }


        public void initiate() {
            ORANGE.printGenericLn("Creating %s", toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps !